# DMZ how it works

Tags: networking, dmz

I am very novice in Networking so hear me out please. I plan to setup the DMZ in my router and expose my CCTV Camera so it is accessible over the internet. My question is the DMZ not inside the firewall, so whatever port rules I set in my router it wont be affected by the rules I place in my firewall?

Comment: I would not recommend DMZ. If it is possible, open only the necessary ports, otherwise, you are out of the router's firewall for that device and could create security issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, but I am a bit confused by the wording of your question. However, in general, low-end consumer routers' "DMZs" typically place a given device "outside" your router's firewall settings (your router firewall settings no longer have any affect on the device). This has the advantage that you no longer need to set up ex. port forwarding. That said, it generally has the disadvantage that *all* incoming requests are sent to that device. So if there is a flaw in ex. the CCTV camera software, attackers may be able to gain access to the device or even potentially your network.